# Zeppelin : How to fill dynamic form dropdown list from sql interpreter

Tags: interpreter, apache-zeppelin, dynamicform

I have connected my Zeppelin to postgresql using the native driver provided in the Zeppelin package. I have a column - `ID` (of a table say `'a'`) which consist of all the ID's required for further processing.

**Example**

```
====================================
ID      |   Value 1     |   Value2
====================================
1       |   23          |   text1
2       |   13          |   text2
3       |   03          |   text3
4       |   99          |   text4
5       |   12          |   text5
```

Now, How do I fill this `ID` column into dynamic form for further user drop down selection?

I know I can use spark context and JDBC drive. But that would be a overkill. All my further processing are with the DB itself for analysis. So I would prefer to create dropdown dynamic form from the psql interpreter itself.